# How can I modify my SELECT code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about my php script.

This is the code for getting the values from db, but I want to get values starting from ID 17 only. How can I do it?

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, pavadinimas, vietos, busena, nuo, iki, kaina FROM kambariai";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
  id, pavadinimas, vietos, busena, nuo, iki, kaina 
  FROM kambariai 
  WHERE id >= 17";
```